# Does experience with an locked weapon count when weapon is eventually unlocked?

Tags: battlefield-v

In Battlefield V, each weapon has its own "level" which counts towards specializations and other advancements that are specific to that gun.

If I pick up a weapon from a downed player that I have not yet unlocked, and gain experience with that weapon, does that experience accrue until I do unlock the weapon or is it lost?

I know the experience counts towards my class and character level experience. I'm specifically asking about the weapon experience levels.

Comment: When ending the match, does the xp bar of the weapon go up in the recap of the won experience ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The experience starts summing up from the moment you unlock the weapon.

You can easily check this by yourself: find a popular weapon you don't have unlocked yet dropped by some dead guy on the battlefield, and try to get 3-4 kills with it before you actually unlock it: these should provide enough experience to bring it to Tier 1 specializations. 3 are usually enough with all the bonus points kill gives, but do 4 just to be sure.

When you finally will unlock the weapon, go checking the experience in the weapon tab: it will be set to zero, and you will not have any of the specialization unlocked. Check again by doing at least 4 kills: you should now see the first specialization getting unlocked for the first time.

Source: Personal Game Experience, checked with mg-42, stg-44 and Kark98

Comment: Some evidence or a source for this would be fantastic, but the anecdote is nice.

Comment: I think it could be simple to experiment, you just need a friend with more unlocked weapons than you and a bit of spare time